# display information of a cell given it's id

Tags: python, csv, pandas

l have a csv file that l process with pandas.

l have two columns :  `id`  and `label`

```
id             label
1656fdgfs       ok 
154685hgfhg45  hello
```

How to display the value of a label if it matches with its id ?

for instance l give `id= 1656fdgfs`  than it prints  `ok`   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), what return `Series` of all values by mask:

```
print (df['id'] == "1656fdgfs")
0     True
1    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

a = df.loc[df['id'] == "1656fdgfs", 'label']
print (a)
0    ok
Name: label, dtype: object
```

If always return only one item (one item `Series`):

```
a = df.loc[df['id'] == "1656fdgfs", 'label'].values[0]
print (a)
ok
```

---

```
a = df.loc[df['id'] == "1656fdgfs", 'label'].item()
print (a)
ok
```

If is possible sometimes is no match need `if` with [`empty`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.empty.html):

```
a = df.loc[df['id'] == "1656fdgfs", 'label']
a = np.nan if a.empty else a.item()
print (a)
ok

a = df.loc[df['id'] == "y", 'label']
a = "No match!" if a.empty else a.item()
print (a)
No match!
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need `loc`. `df[df['id] == "1656fdgfs"]["label"]` should be enough.

Comment: @kabanus - it is better use `loc`, check `In [145]:` in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

Comment: Good resource, I found multiple reasons why you are right.

Comment: @kabanus - Thank you.